# Custom QML object with a writeable array of QString(s) as a property

Tags: c++, qml, qt5

I'm trying to create a property of a custom QML object that will be an array of QString(s). These will be file paths communicated from the QML to c++ code.

When I try to write to the object I get the error:

```
portal.qml:56: Unable to assign QVariantList to [unknown property type]
```

The qml that throws the error:

```
OgreResourceGroup
{
    locations: [ "C:\Client\resources" ]
}
```

The property declaration for locations:

```
Q_PROPERTY( QQmlListProperty<QString> locations READ getLocations WRITE setLocations NOTIFY locationsChanged )
```

The C++ write method in the custom object:

```
void setLocations( const QQmlListProperty<QString>& list );
```

Is the javascript is creating an array of variants instead of an array of QStrings?
If so how do you instantiate a QString?

None of the Qt examples I've looked at implement a writable list.

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Qt docs have a sentence that indicates this can't be done:

```
Generally this constructor should not be used in production code, as a writable QList violates QML's memory management rules.
```

:(

Answer (score 1):

First of all you cannot have "QQmlListProperty" writable. It's only a special object, which should be considered as reference, that QmlEngine writes to.

Second you can use only types that derive from QObject, and QString don't.

All JSON object are keep by Javascript engine internally, and when there are assign to property, there are converted to QVariant ( array have type QMetaType::QVariantList, and object QMetaType::QVariantMap ).

You should just use QVariant, QVariantList or QStringList.

Comment: QString is registered with the QML engine. They say it's usable in javascript but I've never seen the ability to instantiate QString

Comment: @Jay QString is converted to JavaScript native string.